# Split a flat array into a 2d array by starting a new subarray when an empty element is encountered

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I am looking for something similar to `array_chunk()` but using an empty value as the separator.

I have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /some/path:
    [1] => file.csv
    [2] => file.dat
    [3] => 
    [4] => /some/other/path:
    [5] => file.csv
    [6] => file.csv.gz
    [7] => file.dat
    [8] => 
    [9] => /some/other/other/path:
    [10] => file.csv
    [11] => file.dat
)
```

And would like to achieve -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /some/path:
            [1] => file.csv
            [2] => file.dat
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /some/other/path:
            [1] => file.csv
            [2] => file.csv.gz
            [3] => file.dat
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => /some/other/other/path:
            [1] => file.csv
            [2] => file.dat
        )
)
```

Note, I can't just chunk on every 3 as you can see some locations will have more than 1 file.

I can achieve via loop and counter, but I am hoping there is a cleaner method?

Comment: Where are you getting this array from? Maybe there's an even better solution than this.

Comment: @Jack its coming from ftp_nlist('/some/path/*') which returns the array in the above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way I can think of is this loop which I think is pretty clean:

```
/**
 * @param array  $inputArr  The array you wish to split.
 * @param string $splitStr  The string you wish to split by.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function split_arrays($inputArr, $splitStr) {
    $outputArr = array();
    $i         = 0;
    foreach ($inputArr as $data) {
        if ($data == $splitStr) {
            $i++;
            continue;
        }
        $outputArr[$i][] = $data;
    }
    return $outputArr;
}
```

The other way I thought of also uses loops but is not as clean. It searches for the index of the next split string and breaks off that chunk.

```
/**
 * @param array  $inputArr  The array you wish to split.
 * @param string $splitStr  The string you wish to split by.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function split_arrays2($inputArr,$splitStr) {
    $outputArr = array(); $i=0;
    while(count($inputArr)) {
        $index = array_search($splitStr,$inputArr)
        if($index === false) $index = count($inputArr);
        $outputArr[$i++] = array_slice($inputArr,0,$index);
        $inputArr = array_slice($inputArr,$index+1);
    }
    return $outputArr;
}
```

If and only if you are using a string for the split string which is not ever going to show up inside the middle of the other strings (space may or may not be the case for this) then I agree with the others that implode and explode are much simpler. In your case:

```
/**
 * @param array  $inputArr  The array you wish to split.
 * @param string $splitStr  The string you wish to split by.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function split_arrays3($inputArr,$splitStr) {
    $outputArr = array(); $i=0;
    $str = implode("|",$inputArr);
    $arr = explode("|$splitStr|");
    foreach($arr as $i=>$string)
        $outputArr[$i] = explode("|",$string);
    return $outputArr;
}
```

Comment: i think the first and third are the cleanest... and do very appreciate it as I do all the input/code from everyone.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = array();
foreach(explode("\n\n", implode("\n", $arr)) as $k => $v) {
  $res[$k] = explode("\n", $v);
}
```

`$res` will contains the array you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two characters that will not occur in the array string for sure?
If so, suppose they are `#` and `;`

We'll use combination of `implode` and `explode`

Then:

```
$arrstring = implode(';',$old_array);   // Split via ; spearators
$arrstring = str_replace(';;','#',$arrstring); // If two ;; then mark end of array as #
$new_pre_array = explode('#',$arrstring); // Outer array

// Inner array
foreach($new_pre_array as $key => $entry) {
 $temp_sub_array = explode(';',$entry);
 $new_pre_array[$key] = $temp_sub_array;
}

return $new_pre_array;
```

Reference: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$chunked = chunkArray($your_array);


function chunkArray($array){
    $return = array();
    $index = 0;
    foreach($array as $ar){
        if($ar == "" or $ar == null){
            $index++;
        }
        else{
            $return[$index][] = $ar;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was opting to first locate at which places the array `$array` has to be splitted:

```
$splitAt = array_keys($array, '', TRUE);
```

This actually is the most magic. The `array_splice` function then can be used to get the chunks from the input array, only a temporary variable, I named it `$last`:

```
$last = 0;
```

is used to keep track because the length is not the position. Those `$splitAt` are then used to be inserted into the

```
$result = array();
```

`$result` array:

```
foreach($splitAt as $pos) {
    $result[] = array_splice($array, 0, $pos - $last);
    unset($array[0]);
    $last += $pos + 1;
}
```

The leftover chunk from the array is then added as last element:

```
$result[] = $array;
```

And that's it. The full Example ([Demo](http://codepad.org/GOv6BaK4)):

```
/**
 * explode array by delimiter
 *
 * @param mixed $delimiter
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
function array_explode($delimiter, array $array)
{
    $splitAt = array_keys($array, $delimiter, TRUE);
    $last = 0;
    $result = array();
    foreach ($splitAt as $pos) {
        $result[] = array_splice($array, 0, $pos - $last);
        $array && unset($array[0]);
        $last += $pos + 1;
    }
    $result[] = $array;
    return $result;
}

# Usage:

var_dump(array_explode('', $array));
```

I named the function `array_explode` because it works like `explode` on strings but for arrays.

The second option I see (and which might be preferrable) is to loop over the array and process it according to it's value: Either add to the current element or add the current to it:

```
/**
 * explode array by delimiter
 *
 * @param mixed $delimiter
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
function array_explode($delimiter, array $array)
{
    $result[] = &$current;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        if ($value === $delimiter) {
            unset($current);
            $result[] = &$current;
            continue;
        }
        $current[] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I would use the last script with references in a professional application because it avoids needing to keep track of first level indexes in the result array.